# Process finished with exit code 0 python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to python. I have this code. I need to get a result as a json from postoffices, but it only tells that I don't have problems in my code like "Process finished with exit code 0". When I'm trying to `print(get_settlement_postoffices())`, it gives me the same answer.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from datetime import datetime
import json
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, List, Optional, Union

from pochta.enums import PostofficeWorkType
from pochta.utils import HTTPMethod


class Services:
    def get_settlement_postoffices(self, settlement: str,
                                   region: Optional[str] = None,
                                   district: Optional[str] = None) -> List[str]:

        url = '/postoffice/1.0/settlement.offices.codes'

        params = {
            'settlement': settlement,
            'region': region,
            'district': district,
        }

        res = self._client.request(HTTPMethod.GET, url, params=params)
        return res.json()
```

I want to get an array with postal codes of a city I've chosen in a settlement param.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of this class and call its method, like this:

```
myinstance = Services()
print(myinstance.get_settlement_postoffices())
```

The exit code of 0 means that the process has been executed and exited successfully.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I assume the documentation (im working with) isnt working, cuz i ve tried to do you ve said, but still getting no errors.
        res = self._client.request(HTTPMethod.GET, url, params=params)
        return res.json()
        i = Services()
        print(i.get_settlement_postoffices())
Thats the end of my code. But when im trying to get even a status code or something else, nothing changes
i will share with a link on a documentation i use
 https://fogstream.github.io/fs-pochta-api/html/_modules/pochta/api/services.html#Services.get_settlement_postoffices

Comment: Like there if i want to get indexes in the city, for example "Moscow", im doing this way:
in params i change line  'settlement': settlement on a  'settlement': "Moscow"

Comment: The right way is:
 settlement: "Moscow"

Comment: im getting an error `print(i.get_settlement_postoffices())
TypeError: Services.get_settlement_postoffices() missing 1 required positional argument: 'settlement'`

Comment: This how you call functions with keyword arguments:
===================================
def my_function(child3, child2, child1):
  print("The youngest child is " + child3)==================

my_function(child1 = "Emil", child2 = "Tobias", child3 = "Linus") 
==========================================
(code from w3schools)

You should get starter python course, you can't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an instance of that class, before calling the function?
e.g

```
i = Services()
print(i.get_settlement_postoffices())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But anyway doesnt work for me cuz im doing something wrong, but it should work as you ve said

Comment: Can you please share with the whole code? Because im creating an istance of my class at the end like
        `res = self._client.request(HTTPMethod.GET, url, params=params)
         return res.json()
         myinstance = Services()
         print(myinstance.get_settlement_postoffices())`
but i still get Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: im getting an error `print(i.get_settlement_postoffices())
TypeError: Services.get_settlement_postoffices() missing 1 required positional argument: 'settlement'`